Azure Service Bus - REST API - Sending a message to a Session Enabled Topic/Subscription
I am sending messages to a Azure Service Bus topic using REST API - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/send-message-to-queue.
The messages are getting dead lettered with the reason "Session enabled entity doesn't allow a message whose session identifier is null". Since the subscription is session enabled, a "sessionId" is expected to be passed. I see that the SDK supports sending a sessionId but the REST API does not. But I need to use the REST API and can't connect using SDKs because the call is made from within a vended product.
Any thoughts on how to overcome this issue? How can a sessionId be passed via the API?

Can you share the code which you have tried?

from the rest api documentation, you can send sessionid as header: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/send-message-to-queue#request-headers.You need to send the BrokerProperties. BrokerMessage Properties has a field sessionId: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage?view=azure-dotnet-legacy#properties

@AVijay, If    SessionId  is enabled add this code
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("BrokerProperties", "{\"Label\":\"M1\",\"State\":\"Active\",\"TimeToLive\":10,\"SessionId\":\"Hello\"}");

Thanks Thomas for your suggestion. Should have been an answer. I was able send the message successfully by setting a new header property with key as BrokerProperties and value as "{“SessionId”: “{1234}”". Appreciate your response too Pavan.

Thanks @Thomas for your input but the SessionId property you mentioned is part of the .NET SDK for Azure Service Bus, which is available when working within a .NET application that references the Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging namespace.
This property allows you to set the session identifier for a message when sending it to a session-enabled queue or topic using the SDK.
However, since you're constrained to using the REST API and cannot utilize the SDK, you'll need to find a way to mimic the functionality of setting the SessionId through the REST API.

Implementing a small proxy or using an Azure Function or Logic App might be your best bet to inject the SessionId when sending messages.

consoleapp.cs with Rest API using  SessionId:
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
 
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Replace with your Service Bus details
        string serviceNamespace = "sampath";
        string queueName = "sampath";
        string sasToken = "";
        string messageBody = "This is a message.";
 
        // Create the HTTP client
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            // Set the request URI
            string requestUri = $"https://{serviceNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{queueName}/messages?timeout=60";
 
            // Create the message content with corrected content type
            StringContent content = new StringContent(messageBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
 
            // Add required headers
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", sasToken);
 
            // Adding the BrokerProperties header with SessionId
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("BrokerProperties", "{\"Label\":\"M1\",\"State\":\"Active\",\"TimeToLive\":10,\"SessionId\":\"Hello\"}");
 
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Priority", "High");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Customer", "12345,ABC");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = true;
 
            
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, content);
 
            // Check the response
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Message sent successfully with status code: {response.StatusCode}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to send message. Status code: {response.StatusCode}, Reason: {response.ReasonPhrase}");
            }
        }
    }
}

Message sent:

Output:


Just adding a comment here for anyone running into the same issue. It is indeed possible to send a session id in the REST API call. The documentation for that is here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/message-headers-and-properties
